# Volume of the solid obtained by revolving

Tags: area, volume, solid-of-revolution

[To see the question please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceX6C.png)

I found the function is second root of $(x-1)$.

The question I can't find the answer is that:

> Find the volume of the solid obtained by revolving the region $R$
>   about $y$-axis.

Comment: You can use [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to express your question in a better way

Comment: you can look again

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange. You'll receive fewer downvotes if you provide context, show an attempt, and format in MathJax. It helps us help you.